# Cannot find element created after ajax call with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am creating a JQuery UI dialog and setting its html within an ajax call. Part of this is a `form` with its `id` set. However, when I try to find the `form`, it fails. I know that this is because the elements are created after the initial DOM is parsed, but how do I refresh/access this element (basically I want to submit the form using the jQuery Form Plugin).

This is the code:

```
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: lURL,
       data: lData,
       dataType: "json"
      }).
     done( function(response){
       if ( response.success ){
         lDialog = $("<div></div>").dialog( {
           height: "auto",
           maxHeight: 800,
           width: 750,
           autoOpen: false,
           buttons: [
             { id: "saveBtn",
               text: "Save",
               icons: {primary: "ui-icon-check" },
               click: function () {
                 var lForm = lDialog.find("#" + formId);
                 processFileActionSubmit(formId, lForm);//calls AjaxSubmit
                 $(this).dialog("close");
               }
             },
             { id: "cancelBtn",
               text: "Cancel",
               icons: {primary: "ui-icon-close"},
               click: function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
              }
             }],
           close: function (event, ui) { $(this).remove(); },
          resizable: false,
          modal: true
         });
         lDialog.html(response.content);

       };

       lDialog.dialog("open");
      };
    }).
    fail( function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
       alert("Sorry, no info to display.");
    });
```

Any pointers gratefully received.

Comment: If you are wanting to bind events to the form, have a look into delegated events.  If you just want to submit the form once it has been loaded, the you would need to do that after you have appended it to the page

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, but you don't appear to be attaching the dialog element to the DOM? That could be causing a problem.

Comment: I have this working now, but it seems to depend where I try to find the form. I have 3 functions in the js unit. 

displayDilalog() - in the save button function $("#filelist") works

processFileActionSubmit() - called from the save button function: works there

submitTheForm() - called from FileActionSubmit: doesn't work.

Anyway, I now pass the form from the save through the other functions.

Thanks for your input. and so quick!